# Combining two Dimensions in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, dimensions, calculated-field

I have two Dimensions I’m trying to combine into one calculated field. Below are their names and the options for each:
1.  Agree / Disagree/ Overturn
a.  Agree
b.  Disagree
c.  Overturn
2.  Severity
a.  Important
b.  Informational
c.  Minor
d.  Moderate
e.  Severe
For starters I created

```
COUNTD(IF ([Agree / Disagree / Overturn] = 'Agree' 
OR [Agree / Disagree / Overturn] = 'Overturn') 
THEN [Loan Number] 
END)
```

This worked fine, but did not filter out everything I was needing to. I also need to bring in the Severity dimension and keep everything except “Minor”. So I tried the following:

```
COUNTD(IF ([Agree / Disagree / Overturn] = 'Agree'
OR [Agree / Disagree / Overturn] = 'Overturn'
AND [Severity] = 'Moderate'
OR [Severity] = 'Severe'
OR [Severity] = 'Important'
OR [Severity] = 'Informational')
THEN
```

[Loan Number]
    END)
This worked great as well, but only on one month. For the other two months of the quarter the count is off by several. I don’t have any other filters on that should cause it to work with one month and not with others.
Thoughts?

Comment: I know that adding these two measures to filter seems obvious (and does work for one column), but i'm trying to calculate a Gross, Valid and Net measurement in one Cross Tab. So i need to complete this via a calculated field.

Comment: Looks like you got to replace your [Agree / Disagree / Overturn] checks with [Agree / Disagree / Overturn] != 'Disagree', and replace [Severity] checks with one [Severity] != 'Minor'.

Current calculation does not work as intended, because AND operation has a higher priority than OR.

Comment: Much more efficient means for that calculation. Thank you.